# Help with RenounceOwnership guideline using Multisig

Tags: multisignature

I'm quite new here where I used Safewallet as a smart contract deployment.
Right now,  I'm trying to renounce my ownership in polyscan, but it keeps failing.
Is there any complete guideline for me to renounce the ownership since is using multisig and I have all my wallet ready.

Can you assist me what should I do next to renounce the ownership of the contract address with complete tutorial using Safewallet?